# Kafka/MSK: 'Topic authorization failed for topics' - EC2 console producer

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka

I can't set up a working console producer via an EC2 instance when using IAM authentication.

With the following IAM policy applied, a console consumer works successfully:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kafka-cluster:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:kafka:<region>:<account-id>:cluster/<cluster_name>/<cluster_uuid>"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

but attempting a producer gives:

"*ERROR [Producer clientId=console-producer] Aborting producer batches due to fatal error (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ClusterAuthorizationException: Cluster authorization failed.*"

AWS documentation states:

"*For Kafka versions 2.8.0 and above, the WriteDataIdempotently permission is deprecated...
To work around this, we recommend using a policy similar to the sample below:...*"

I am using Kafka 3.5.1, so tried implemented the recommended policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kafka-cluster:Connect",
                "kafka-cluster:AlterCluster",
                "kafka-cluster:DescribeCluster",
                "kafka-cluster:WriteDataIdempotently"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:kafka:us-east-1:0123456789012:cluster/MyTestCluster/abcd1234-0123-abcd-5678-1234abcd-1"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kafka-cluster:*Topic*",
                "kafka-cluster:WriteData",
                "kafka-cluster:ReadData"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:kafka:us-east-1:0123456789012:topic/MyTestCluster/abcd1234-0123-abcd-5678-1234abcd-1/TestTopic"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and again, a consumer can successfully be set up for the desired topic, and a producer is unsuccessful:

"*WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 () could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2024-03-12 13:21:31,567] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Bootstrap broker  (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)*"